# Creating Button in a page upon another button click

Tags: javascript, html, button, click

I'm new to HTML and JS so i would be very grateful if someone helped me with the following - I have a normal page that contains a plus (+) button:

```html
<button style="background-color:#0099CC" id= "firstbutton" type="submit"     data-role="button" data-theme="b">Add
```

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#firstbutton').click(function(){
  $(this).before('<button type="submit">add</button>');
}); 
});
</script>
```

I want to add another button above the add button when I click on the add button. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jquery which is a javascript library, you need to first [download](http://jquery.com/download/) it or you can include this in the head section of your HTML

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

after doing it inside the script tag which will be below the above inclusion:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#firstbutton').click(function(){
   $(this).before('<button type="submit">add</button>');
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: can i make this if i edited a little and the add button opens a page to enter  the dynamic new button name then i click submit and by clicking submit i place the new button with the new name entered above the add button ?

Comment: I think the code will work in the scenario if I understood correctly that you want the submit functionality to happen and also add the button as I am NOT preventing the default action of the submit button to happen.

Comment: So you are saying that you want to add one more submit button before some other button while clicking on submit?? Yes you can do it by the above code. Just for the reference http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGypdL

Comment: No problem! if the code worked for you. You might want to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Use following jquery code:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
$(this).parent().prepend("<button style=\"background-color:#0099CC\">Add</button>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="background-color:#0099CC" id= "firstbutton" type="submit" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Add</button>
```